# Custome Middleware using it in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-middleware

How can I use this custome middleware HouseOwnerMiddleware. My thought is that if I can use `@guest` in blade, why not use `@houesowner` as well?

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'houseowner' => \App\Http\Middleware\HouseOwnerMiddleware::class, // THIS PART
    ];
```

But I can not do this. How would you recommend me to use it?

```
@houseowner
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/houseowner/roomid/1/userid/{{Auth::id()}}/images/create">
     Upload images
</a>
@end
```

The custom middleware is here, just for simplification I have made the if statement TRUE. So everyone would pass this statement for now.

```
class HouseOwnerMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(true){
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to add more information to your question in order for someone to give you a good answer. What does this middleware do? How does it relate to your blade templates? What does `@houseowner` do as a blade directive?

Comment: @Spholt I have updated it. Is that enough or do you need more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, i'm not sure what you are trying to do here.

---

**Middleware**

A `Middleware` is used to apply logic in the middle of a request (e.g. checking authorization, adding redirects, modifying the request). *The middleware you have written will run but do nothing to your request!*

```
if (true) {
    return $next($request);
}
```

The if condition will always pass but all it does is say "move onto the next part of the request"

Documentation on Middleware can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#introduction)

---

**Blade Directives**

If you want to extend `Blade` and register new directives like `@houseowner`, you would do this in a `ServiceProvider` such as `AppServiceProvider` like so:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Blade::directive('houseowner', function ($expression) {
        // Return your custom markup here
        return "<?php echo "houseowner"; ?>";
    });
}
```

Documentation on extending Blade templates can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#extending-blade)

---

**Blade Logic**

What i suspect you are trying to do is some conditional logic to display an `a` tag if the user is a "houseowner"?

You can do this with standard blade logic statements like so:

```
@if (Auth::user->isHouseOwner())
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/houseowner/roomid/1/userid/{{Auth::id()}}/images/create">
     Upload images
</a>
@endif
```

You will need to create a method called `isHouseOwner()` on your `User` model of course.

---

It sounds like you are fairly new to Laravel, I would strongly suggest spending some time reading through the documentation. Good Luck!

Comment: I'm aware that the statement is true in the middleware, so everyone can access it. My question was for the @houseowner which you nicely explain. Thanks for that :)